# Kubernetes and ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: nginx, docker, containers, kubernetes

I've got a pod with 2 containers, both running nginx.  One is running on port 80, the other on port 88.  I have no trouble accessing the one on port 80, but can't seem to access the one on port 88.  When I try, I get:

This site can’t be reached
   The connection was reset.
   ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

So here's the details.

1)  The container is defined in the deployment YAML as:

```
    - name: rss-reader
      image: nickchase/nginx-php-rss:v3
      ports:
        - containerPort: 88
```

2)  I created the service with:

```
kubectl expose deployment rss-site --port=88 --target-port=88 --type=NodePort --name=backend
```

3)  This created a service of:

```
root@kubeclient:/home/ubuntu# kubectl describe service backend
Name:                   backend
Namespace:              default
Labels:                 app=web
Selector:               app=web
Type:                   NodePort
IP:             11.1.250.209
Port:                   <unset> 88/TCP
NodePort:               <unset> 31754/TCP
Endpoints:              10.200.41.2:88,10.200.9.2:88
Session Affinity:       None
No events.
```

And when I tried to access it, I used the URL

```
http://[nodeip]:31754/index.php
```

Now, when I instantiate the container manually with Docker, this works.

So anybody have a clue what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

My presumtion is that you're using the wrong access IP. Are you trying to access the minion's IP address and port 31754?

Comment: Yes, I was. Should I be using something else?